# Uncaught exception not enough arguments nsresult error after using twitter widget in Lotus Notes XPage

Tags: javascript, twitter, xpages

I am using the twitter widget from twitter in my XPage in lotus notes, I simply inserted the script into the Source of my XPage, sometimes the widget works, sometimes not, but it always gives me an error

Widget script:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Dr_hosea" width="250" data-widget-id="332843009685209088">Tweets by @Dr_hosea</a>
<script>
! function (d, s, id) {
    try {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    } catch (err) {}
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: ...
```

Comment: What line of code throws the error? The error statement should tell you that. So please update your question with that info

Comment: I'd also suggest just trying this in a basic HTML file to make sure the code itself is clean... nothing in the code snippet you posted is inherently related to XPages. I'm also wondering what the initial ! is for... that's a negation operator in JavaScript, and there doesn't seem to be any reason to negate the result of that function.